# pandas apply function that returns multiple values to rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, iterable-unpacking

I have a dataframe with a timeindex and 3 columns containing the coordinates of a 3D vector:

```
                         x             y             z
ts
2014-05-15 10:38         0.120117      0.987305      0.116211
2014-05-15 10:39         0.117188      0.984375      0.122070
2014-05-15 10:40         0.119141      0.987305      0.119141
2014-05-15 10:41         0.116211      0.984375      0.120117
2014-05-15 10:42         0.119141      0.983398      0.118164
```

I would like to apply a transformation to each row that also returns a vector

```
def myfunc(a, b, c):
    do something
    return e, f, g
```

but if I do:

```
df.apply(myfunc, axis=1)
```

I end up with a Pandas series whose elements are tuples. This is beacause apply will take the result of myfunc without unpacking it. How can I change myfunc so that I obtain a new df with 3 columns?

**Edit:**

All solutions below work. The Series solution does allow for column names, the List solution seem to execute faster.

```
def myfunc1(args):
    e=args[0] + 2*args[1]
    f=args[1]*args[2] +1
    g=args[2] + args[0] * args[1]
    return pd.Series([e,f,g], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])

def myfunc2(args):
    e=args[0] + 2*args[1]
    f=args[1]*args[2] +1
    g=args[2] + args[0] * args[1]
    return [e,f,g]

%timeit df.apply(myfunc1 ,axis=1)

100 loops, best of 3: 4.51 ms per loop

%timeit df.apply(myfunc2 ,axis=1)

100 loops, best of 3: 2.75 ms per loop
```

Comment: It's useful to say *"unpack the tuple(/list) returned by the function into multiple columns"*. Instead of *"This is beacause apply will take the result of myfunc without unpacking it. How can I change myfunc so that I obtain a new df with 3 columns?"** Tagged [tag:tuple-unpacking]/iterable-unpacking

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just return a list instead of tuple.

```
In [81]: df
Out[81]: 
                            x         y         z
ts                                               
2014-05-15 10:38:00  0.120117  0.987305  0.116211
2014-05-15 10:39:00  0.117188  0.984375  0.122070
2014-05-15 10:40:00  0.119141  0.987305  0.119141
2014-05-15 10:41:00  0.116211  0.984375  0.120117
2014-05-15 10:42:00  0.119141  0.983398  0.118164

[5 rows x 3 columns]

In [82]: def myfunc(args):
   ....:        e=args[0] + 2*args[1]
   ....:        f=args[1]*args[2] +1
   ....:        g=args[2] + args[0] * args[1]
   ....:        return [e,f,g]
   ....: 

In [83]: df.apply(myfunc ,axis=1)
Out[83]: 
                            x         y         z
ts                                               
2014-05-15 10:38:00  2.094727  1.114736  0.234803
2014-05-15 10:39:00  2.085938  1.120163  0.237427
2014-05-15 10:40:00  2.093751  1.117629  0.236770
2014-05-15 10:41:00  2.084961  1.118240  0.234512
2014-05-15 10:42:00  2.085937  1.116202  0.235327
```

Comment: This does not work. It returns a Series whose elements are lists. I'm on pandas 0.18.1

Comment: See U2EF1 response below - wrap the result list into a pd.Series()

Answer (score 93):

Return `Series` and it will put them in a DataFrame.

```
def myfunc(a, b, c):
    do something
    return pd.Series([e, f, g])
```

This has the bonus that you can give labels to each of the resulting columns. If you return a DataFrame it just inserts multiple rows for the group.

Comment: see more examples at [flexible apply](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/groupby.html#flexible-apply)

Comment: The series answer seems to be the canonical one. However, on version 0.18.1 the series solution takes about 4x longer than running apply multiple times.

Comment: Wouldn't it be super inefficient to create an entire `pd.Series` on each iteration?

Comment: I get a "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'index'" when trying this approach, but not sure why its trying to get the index from one of the vales (float)?

(Edit) Issue was I had two return statements, one just had Nan, that needed to be wrapped in a pd.Series() as well.

Comment: to add a bit to this nice answer, one can further do `new_vars = ['e', 'f', 'g']` and `df[new_vars] = df.apply(my_func, axis=1)`

Answer (score 44):

Based on the excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23690329/304209) by @U2EF1, I've created a handy function that applies a specified function that returns tuples to a dataframe field, and expands the result back to the dataframe.

```
def apply_and_concat(dataframe, field, func, column_names):
    return pd.concat((
        dataframe,
        dataframe[field].apply(
            lambda cell: pd.Series(func(cell), index=column_names))), axis=1)
```

Usage:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3], index=['a', 'b', 'c'], columns=['A'])
print df
   A
a  1
b  2
c  3

def func(x):
    return x*x, x*x*x

print apply_and_concat(df, 'A', func, ['x^2', 'x^3'])

   A  x^2  x^3
a  1    1    1
b  2    4    8
c  3    9   27
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: This is great. Saved me a lot of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

Some of the other people's answers contain mistakes, so I've summarized them below. The perfect answer is below.

Prepare the dataset. The version of pandas uses `1.1.5`.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import timeit

# check pandas version
print(pd.__version__)
# 1.1.5

# prepare DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [0.120117, 0.117188, 0.119141, 0.116211, 0.119141],
    'y': [0.987305, 0.984375, 0.987305, 0.984375, 0.983398],
    'z': [0.116211, 0.122070, 0.119141, 0.120117, 0.118164]},
    index=[
        '2014-05-15 10:38',
        '2014-05-15 10:39',
        '2014-05-15 10:40',
        '2014-05-15 10:41',
        '2014-05-15 10:42'],
    columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
df.index.name = 'ts'
#                          x         y         z
# ts                                            
# 2014-05-15 10:38  0.120117  0.987305  0.116211
# 2014-05-15 10:39  0.117188  0.984375  0.122070
# 2014-05-15 10:40  0.119141  0.987305  0.119141
# 2014-05-15 10:41  0.116211  0.984375  0.120117
# 2014-05-15 10:42  0.119141  0.983398  0.118164
```

### Solution 01.

Returns [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) in the apply function.

```py
def myfunc1(args):
    e = args[0] + 2*args[1]
    f = args[1]*args[2] + 1
    g = args[2] + args[0] * args[1]
    return pd.Series([e, f, g])

df[['e', 'f', 'g']] = df.apply(myfunc1, axis=1)
#                          x         y         z         e         f         g
# ts
# 2014-05-15 10:38  0.120117  0.987305  0.116211  2.094727  1.114736  0.234803
# 2014-05-15 10:39  0.117188  0.984375  0.122070  2.085938  1.120163  0.237427
# 2014-05-15 10:40  0.119141  0.987305  0.119141  2.093751  1.117629  0.236770
# 2014-05-15 10:41  0.116211  0.984375  0.120117  2.084961  1.118240  0.234512
# 2014-05-15 10:42  0.119141  0.983398  0.118164  2.085937  1.116202  0.235327

t1 = timeit.timeit(
    'df.apply(myfunc1, axis=1)',
    globals=dict(df=df, myfunc1=myfunc1), number=10000)
print(round(t1, 3), 'seconds')
# 14.571 seconds
```

### Solution 02.

Use [`result_type ='expand'`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) when applying.

```py
def myfunc2(args):
    e = args[0] + 2*args[1]
    f = args[1]*args[2] + 1
    g = args[2] + args[0] * args[1]
    return [e, f, g]

df[['e', 'f', 'g']] = df.apply(myfunc2, axis=1, result_type='expand')
#                          x         y         z         e         f         g
# ts                                                                          
# 2014-05-15 10:38  0.120117  0.987305  0.116211  2.094727  1.114736  0.234803
# 2014-05-15 10:39  0.117188  0.984375  0.122070  2.085938  1.120163  0.237427
# 2014-05-15 10:40  0.119141  0.987305  0.119141  2.093751  1.117629  0.236770
# 2014-05-15 10:41  0.116211  0.984375  0.120117  2.084961  1.118240  0.234512
# 2014-05-15 10:42  0.119141  0.983398  0.118164  2.085937  1.116202  0.235327

t2 = timeit.timeit(
    "df.apply(myfunc2, axis=1, result_type='expand')",
    globals=dict(df=df, myfunc2=myfunc2), number=10000)
print(round(t2, 3), 'seconds')
# 9.907 seconds
```

### Solution 03.

If you want to make it faster, use [`np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). Note that args cannot be a single argument when using `np.vectorize`.

```py
def myfunc3(args0, args1, args2):
    e = args0 + 2*args1
    f = args1*args2 + 1
    g = args2 + args0 * args1
    return [e, f, g]

df[['e', 'f', 'g']] = pd.DataFrame(np.row_stack(np.vectorize(myfunc3, otypes=['O'])(df['x'], df['y'], df['z'])), index=df.index)
#                          x         y         z         e         f         g
# ts                                                                          
# 2014-05-15 10:38  0.120117  0.987305  0.116211  2.094727  1.114736  0.234803
# 2014-05-15 10:39  0.117188  0.984375  0.122070  2.085938  1.120163  0.237427
# 2014-05-15 10:40  0.119141  0.987305  0.119141  2.093751  1.117629  0.236770
# 2014-05-15 10:41  0.116211  0.984375  0.120117  2.084961  1.118240  0.234512
# 2014-05-15 10:42  0.119141  0.983398  0.118164  2.085937  1.116202  0.235327

t3 = timeit.timeit(
    "pd.DataFrame(np.row_stack(np.vectorize(myfunc3, otypes=['O'])(df['x'], df['y'], df['z'])), index=df.index)",
    globals=dict(pd=pd, np=np, df=df, myfunc3=myfunc3), number=10000)
print(round(t3, 3), 'seconds')
# 1.598 seconds
```

Answer (score 20):

I've tried returning a tuple (I was using functions like `scipy.stats.pearsonr` which return that kind of structures) but It returned a 1D Series instead of a Dataframe which was I expected. If I created a Series manually the performance was worse, so I fixed It using the `result_type` as explained in the [official API documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

> Returning a Series inside the function is similar to passing
> result_type='expand'. The resulting column names will be the Series
> index.

So you could edit your code this way:

```
def myfunc(a, b, c):
    # do something
    return (e, f, g)

df.apply(myfunc, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

Comment: I like this one, and it seems the most pandaic, while only compatible with pandas >= 0.0.23 ([per Genarito's link to the api documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html))

Comment: if you wish to create two or three (or n) new columns in your dataframe, you can use: 
`df['e'], d['f'], d['g'] = df.apply(myfunc, axis=1, result_type='expand').T.values`

Comment: Can we use .apply to return more number of rows than present at df to create a diluted copy? Lets say df had 100 rows and function return 100 rows for each row and resultant dataframe should have 100*100 rows. Possible?

Comment: Sincerely, I don't know. Perhaps the best you can do is another Stack Overflow question to have a custom best answer

Comment: I had to use df['e'], d['f'], d['g'] = df.apply(myfunc, axis=1, result_type='expand').T.values as suggested by @spen.smith.  Without that, the values of directly assigning columns was 0 and 1 (e.g. df["A"], df["B"] = df.apply(foo, axis=1, result_type="expand")  with foo returning ["A", "B"] or ("A","B") would give the columns A and B the values 0 and 1, respectively.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 11):

Found a possible solution, by changing myfunc to return an np.array like this:

```
import numpy as np

def myfunc(a, b, c):
    do something
    return np.array((e, f, g))
```

any better solution?

Comment: Returning numpy array seems the best in terms of performance. For 100K rows, returning numpy array to get DataFrame columns takes 1.55 seconds; using return Series takes 39.7 seconds.  Significant difference in performance here

Answer (score 5):

Pandas 1.0.5 has DataFrame.apply with parameter **result_type** that can help here.
from the docs:

```
These only act when axis=1 (columns):

‘expand’ : list-like results will be turned into columns.

 ‘reduce’ : returns a Series if possible rather than expanding list-like results. This 
 is the opposite of ‘expand’.

‘broadcast’ : results will be broadcast to the original shape of the DataFrame, the 
original index and columns will be retained.
```