# Create multiple pandas DataFrame columns from applying a function with multiple returns

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to apply a function with multiple returns to a `pandas DataFrame` and put the results in separate new columns in that `DataFrame`.

So given something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})

def add_subtract(a, b):
  return (a + b, a - b)
```

The goal is a single command that calls `add_subtract` on `a` and `b` to create two new columns in `df`: `sum` and `difference`.

I thought something like this might work:

```
(df['sum'], df['difference']) = df.apply(
    lambda row: add_subtract(row['a'], row['b']), axis=1)
```

But it yields this error:

> ----> 9     lambda row: add_subtract(row['a'], row['b']), axis=1)
>
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

**EDIT:** In addition to the below answers, [pandas apply function that returns multiple values to rows in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690284/pandas-apply-function-that-returns-multiple-values-to-rows-in-pandas-dataframe) shows that the function can be modified to return a list or `Series`, i.e.:

```
def add_subtract_list(a, b):
  return [a + b, a - b]

df[['sum', 'difference']] = df.apply(
    lambda row: add_subtract_list(row['a'], row['b']), axis=1)
```

or

```
def add_subtract_series(a, b):
  return pd.Series((a + b, a - b))

df[['sum', 'difference']] = df.apply(
    lambda row: add_subtract_series(row['a'], row['b']), axis=1)
```

both work (the latter being equivalent to Wen's accepted answer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding `pd.Series`

```
df[['sum', 'difference']] = df.apply(
    lambda row: pd.Series(add_subtract(row['a'], row['b'])), axis=1)
df
```

yields

```
   a  b  sum  difference
0  1  4    5          -3
1  2  5    7          -3
2  3  6    9          -3
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why `pd.Series` is needed here?

Comment: @MaxGhenis    You have tuple as result in your function   , so , we pass tuple to pd.Series , this will reconstruct the column of tuple to two pd.Series (Dataframe), more info  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550414/how-to-split-column-of-tuples-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: I wonder if `row['a']` and `row['b']` will actually work. Usually this kind of reference should not work inside of `apply()`

Comment: @FedericoDorato: You can use either `row['a']` or even `row.a`  inside apply as long as there's a lambda.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be to use `pd.DataFrame.assign` as follows:

```
df.assign(**{k:v for k,v in zip(['sum', 'difference'], add_subtract(df.a, df.b))})
```

Should yield:

```
   a  b  difference  sum
0  1  4          -3    5
1  2  5          -3    7
2  3  6          -3    9
```

#### Clarifications:

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is a builtin function that returns an iterator of tuples, where the *i-th tuple* contains the *i-th element* from each of the argument sequences or iterables. For instance, `list(zip(['sum', 'difference'], [df.a + df.b], df.a - df.b))` should return `[('sum', df.a + df.b), ('difference', df.a - df.b)]`.

[`**`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) in front of a dictionary object serves as an operator that unpacks the combination of `key` and `value` pairs. In essence, the unpacking could be represented as something like this: `sum=df.a + df.b, difference=df.a - df.b`.

In sum, when combined, you get something like the following:

```
df.assign(sum=df.a + df.b, difference=df.a - df.b)
```

Follow the provided links to both `zip` and the `**` operator in front of a dictionary object to get a better idea of how these useful tools work beyond this particular example.

Comment: This is intriguing: I'm relatively new to Python (mostly an R user), so could you explain what the `**` and `zip` are doing here? Seems like a useful construct. I accepted Wen's answer as it differed least from my guess, but upvoted this and can change if this would be significantly better performance-wise.

Comment: @MaxGhenis you can treat the zip in python is list of list in R , in R we need   `unlist` here is the example of R :-) (PS, I am 50% R user too :-) ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame

Comment: That statement is a bit lacking. Data structures in R are not that easily translated in python data structures. The closest to `zip` I can think of in R is the [`transpose`](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/transpose.html) function from the [`purrr`](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/) package. Even that doesn't really work the same way in all cases.