# How to return multiple values including a list in pandas apply function?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, apply

I want to apply a function that returns multiple values to my data frame such that these values are collected in different columns. How do we achieve this?

Minimum Reproducible code:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'col2':['a','b','c','d','e']})
```

Which returns the table:

|  | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a |
| 1 | 2 | b |
| 2 | 3 | c |
| 3 | 4 | d |
| 4 | 5 | e |

Now I want one of the return values to be a list, so following the answer from [this StackOverFlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483254/python-pandas-insert-list-into-a-cell), I made an empty column `astype(object)`

```
import numpy as np
df['e']=np.nan
df['e']=df['e'].astype('object')
```

Following the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690284/pandas-apply-function-that-returns-multiple-values-to-rows-in-pandas-dataframe) I am returning the value like this:

```
def funct(a,b):
  c=str(a)+b
  d=b+str(a)
  return[c,d,[c,d]]
```

If I want to save the output into three columns c,d,e, I am trying:

```
df[['c','d','e']]=df.apply(lambda x: funct(x['col1'],x['col2']), axis=1)
```

Which gives the error:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

If I run

```
df['c','d','e']=df.apply(lambda x: funct(x['col1'],x['col2']), axis=1)
```

The return value is:

```
| i|col1| col2 |(c, d, e)         |
|:-|:--:|------|------------------:
|0 |  1 |  a   |[1a, a1, [1a, a1]]|
|1 |  2 |  b   |[2b, b2, [2b, b2]]|
|2 |  3 |  c   |[3c, c3, [3c, c3]]|
|3 |  4 |  d   |[4d, d4, [4d, d4]]|
|4 |  5 |  e   |[5e, e5, [5e, e5]]|
```

How do I get:

```
|  | col1 |col2| c | d | e      |
|:-|:----:|:--:|:-:|:-:|------- |
|0 | 1    |a   |1a |a1 |[1a, a1]|
|1 | 2    |b   |2b |b2 |[2b, b2]|
|2 | 3    |c   |3c |c3 |[3c, c3]|
|3 | 4    |d   |4d |d4 |[4d, d4]|
|4 | 5    |e   |5e |e5 |[5e, e5]|
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23690329/2901002

Comment: Fo rme working `return pd.Series([c,d,[c,d]])`

Comment: and then `df[['c','d','e']]=df.apply(lambda x: funct(x['col1'],x['col2']), axis=1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do `result_type='expand'` in apply with your existing function:

```
df[['c','d','e']]=(df.apply(lambda x: funct(x['col1'],x['col2']),
                  axis=1,result_type='expand')
```

---

```
print(df)

   col1 col2   c   d         e
0     1    a  1a  a1  [1a, a1]
1     2    b  2b  b2  [2b, b2]
2     3    c  3c  c3  [3c, c3]
3     4    d  4d  d4  [4d, d4]
4     5    e  5e  e5  [5e, e5]
```

Comment: @jezrael Thank you , changed to wiki

Comment: My first idea was if add answer to dupe, but already exist :(

Comment: @jezrael Np :-)

Comment: The question is not really a duplicate because I was facing an issue with two separate questions and the accepted answer there did not work. But yes this solution is much better. I do not need to instantiate with nan values with this too.