# Merge dataframe with another dataframe created from apply function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe, `df`, of salary data:

```
State,Annual Salary
New York, 132826
New Hampshire,128704
California,127388
Vermont,121599
Idaho,120011
```

And a function, `get_taxes_from_api` that calls an API and returns tax numbers for an input State and Annual Salary as a data frame with only 1 row like this:

```
State,annual.fica.amount,annual.federal.amount,annual.state.amount
North Carolina,8918,40334,6364
```

it is of type: `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` not series.
I want to call the API on each row of df and then merge each of the resulting 1 row data frames. Something like:

```
State,Annual Salary,annual.fica.amount,annual.federal.amount,annual.state.amount
North Carolina, 116500,8918,40334,6364
New York, 132826, . . . 
New Hampshire,128704, . . . 
California,127388, . . . 
Vermont,121599, . . . 
Idaho,120011, . . .
```

How do I do this? I ran into an error that my lambda below created a Series instead of a dataframe so went down this rabbit hole of using result_type=expand like here ['https://stackoverflow.com/a/62849468/2415706'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62849468/2415706) but it is still broken:

```
all_tax_df = df[['State','Annual Salary']].apply(lambda row: get_taxes_from_api(row['State'],row['Annual Salary']), axis=1, result_type='expand')


# merge all_tax_df with df on 'State'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify `result_type` for the [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) call when the applied function inside `.apply()` returns a pandas Series.  From the [official document](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

> Returning a Series inside the function is similar to passing
> result_type='expand'. The resulting column names will be the Series
> index.

Moreover, for the default `result_type=None`:

> The default behaviour (None) depends on the return value of the
> applied function: .... if the apply function returns a Series these are
> expanded to columns.

As your API (the applied function inside `.apply()` call) returns a 1-row DataFrame, you can readily convert it to a Series by the [`.squeeze()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) call, like below:

```
df[['State','Annual Salary']].apply(
    lambda row: get_taxes_from_api(row['State'], row['Annual Salary']).squeeze(), axis=1)
```

The result of this `apply()` call contains only the columns returned by the API call, which does not include the column `Annual Salary` in your original DataFrame.  You can call [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to merge the original dataframe with the resulting dataframe returned from `apply()` to get your desired layout.  You can do the 2 steps in one line:

```
all_tax_df = df.merge(df[['State','Annual Salary']].apply(
    lambda row: get_taxes_from_api(row['State'], row['Annual Salary']).squeeze(), axis=1))
```

### Test Run

```
col = ['State','Annual Salary']
dat = [['New York', 132826], ['New Hampshire',128704], ['California',127388], ['Vermont',121599], ['Idaho',120011]]
df = pd.DataFrame(dat, columns=col)

def get_taxes_from_api(state, annual_salary):
    return pd.DataFrame({'State': [state], 
                         'annual.fica.amount': [int(annual_salary * 0.067)], 
                         'annual.federal.amount': [int(annual_salary * 0.3)], 
                         'annual.state.amount': [int(annual_salary * 0.048)]})


all_tax_df = df.merge(df[['State','Annual Salary']].apply(
    lambda row: get_taxes_from_api(row['State'], row['Annual Salary']).squeeze(), axis=1))



print(all_tax_df)




           State  Annual Salary  annual.fica.amount  annual.federal.amount  annual.state.amount
0       New York         132826                8899                  39847                 6375
1  New Hampshire         128704                8623                  38611                 6177
2     California         127388                8534                  38216                 6114
3        Vermont         121599                8147                  36479                 5836
4          Idaho         120011                8040                  36003                 5760
```

Comment: I tried what you have here fixing that typo, still doesn't work. 

get_taxes_from_api doesn't return a pd.Series, it returns a dataframe. Here's what I get when I write a test printing its type and what it returns:

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
   annual.fica.amount  annual.federal.amount  annual.state.amount State Initial  State  
0                7650                15103.5                    0            TX  Texas                 `

Comment: @user2415706   See my edit above to cater for when DataFrame is returned by the api     I have tested it with modified model api function.

Comment: Ok thank you that modification that casts back into series works!

Comment: @user2415706  I have further simplified the codes by defining a custom function so that we don't need to call api twice in the lambda function.

Comment: @user2415706  The the 1-row dataframe can readily be converted to a pandas Series by using `.squeeze()`.  See my consolidated edit above.  The codes can be much simplified and used as the final version.

Comment: Thank you for this update, yeah it looks much nicer with squeeze().

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply by assigning directly the apply result to new columns :

```
df[["annual.fica.amount","annual.federal.amount","annual.state.amount"]]=( 
    df[['State','Annual Salary']].apply(lambda row: get_taxes_from_api(row['State'],row['Annual Salary']), axis=1)
)
```

Merging would be a good idea if you'd get the whole dataframe in one call to the api (which might be more efficient)

Answer (score 1):

If you really do not want the result as a series, you can easily convert it to DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd    

all_tax_df = pd.DataFrame(df[['State','Annual Salary']].apply(lambda row: get_taxes_from_api(row['State'],row['Annual Salary']), axis=1, result_type='expand'))
```

Comment: tried this, I get: `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`, get_taxes_from_api returns a dataframe already, I wrote a test and this is what that test outputs as the type and the output:

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>    annual.fica.amount  annual.federal.amount  annual.state.amount State Initial  State   0                7650                15103.5                    0            TX  Texas`