# Merge dataframes returned from applying function to DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

My question is related to this question:

[Merge dataframe with another dataframe created from apply function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66915602/merge-dataframe-with-another-dataframe-created-from-apply-function)

Here is my version of code:

```
col = ['State','Annual Salary']
dat = [['New York', 132826], ['New Hampshire',128704], ['California',127388], ['Vermont',121599], ['Idaho',120011]]
df = pd.DataFrame(dat, columns=col)

def get_taxes_from_api(state, annual_salary):
    return pd.DataFrame({'State': [state, state], 
                         'annual.fica.amount': [int(annual_salary * 0.067),
                                                int(annual_salary * 1.067)], 
                         'annual.federal.amount': [int(annual_salary * 0.3),
                                                   int(annual_salary * 1.3)], 
                         'annual.state.amount': [int(annual_salary * 0.048),
                                                 int(annual_salary * 1.048)]})
```

How do I apply get_taxes_from_api to each row of df and combine the returned dataframes into on dataframe?

The only difference is that my function returns a multiple-row dataframe, not a 1-row dataframe. So the solution to that question above does not work for my situation. (And I don't have enought reputation to leave a comment there.)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but here's one way that doesn't use apply

```
col = ['State','Annual Salary']
dat = [['New York', 132826], ['New Hampshire',128704], ['California',127388], ['Vermont',121599], ['Idaho',120011]]
df = pd.DataFrame(dat, columns=col)

#Create the "first" row of each state from your function by adding columns
df['annual.fica.amount'] = df['Annual Salary'].multiply(0.067)
df['annual.federal.amount'] = df['Annual Salary'].multiply(0.3)
df['annual.state.amount'] = df['Annual Salary'].multiply(0.048)

#Create the "second" row of each state as a new df
cumulative_df = df.copy()
cumulative_df['annual.fica.amount'] += cumulative_df['Annual Salary']
cumulative_df['annual.federal.amount'] += cumulative_df['Annual Salary']
cumulative_df['annual.state.amount'] += cumulative_df['Annual Salary']

#Concatenate the two tables and sort so the states are right next to each other
final_df = pd.concat((df,cumulative_df)).sort_values('State').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `concat` for the nested DataFrame

```
nested_df = df.apply(lambda x: get_taxes_from_api(x["State"],x["Annual Salary"]),axis=1)

result = pd.DataFrame()

for element in nested_df:
    result = pd.concat([result,element])
```

result:

```
print(result)
```

|  | State | annual.fica.amount | annual.federal.amount | annual.state.amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | New York | 8899 | 39847 | 6375 |
| 1 | New York | 141725 | 172673 | 139201 |
| 0 | New Hampshire | 8623 | 38611 | 6177 |
| 1 | New Hampshire | 137327 | 167315 | 134881 |
| 0 | California | 8534 | 38216 | 6114 |
| 1 | California | 135922 | 165604 | 133502 |
| 0 | Vermont | 8147 | 36479 | 5836 |
| 1 | Vermont | 129746 | 158078 | 127435 |
| 0 | Idaho | 8040 | 36003 | 5760 |
| 1 | Idaho | 128051 | 156014 | 125771 |

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new join key among the two dfs and do pd.merge. See here:

```
df["df_merge_key"] = "#"
df_after_apply["df_merge_key"] = "#"
details_df = pd.merge(df, df_after_apply, how="left", on="df_merge_key").drop(labels=["df_merge_key"], axis=1)
```

This is simpler and neater in my opinion.