# Code syntax for retrieving, adding multiple return values from funciton

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Lets say i have a dataframe df with columns a, b like below:
a b
1 4
2 5
3 6

Lets assume we have similar function which returns 2 values

```
fun calc(a, b, type):
 if type=='both':
  c=a+b
  d=a-b
return c, d
```

how to store the returned values to a new column in dataframe df
i tried below syntax, but getting error mentioning

```
df[['c', 'd']] = df['a', 'b'].apply(calc, type='both', axis=1)
```

but getting error as calc got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: Neither of the code snippets run. functions are defined with `def` not `fun` in python. I think you also meant `df[['a', 'b']].apply(calc...` to select those two columns.

Comment: See: [pandas apply function that returns multiple values to rows in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690284/pandas-apply-function-that-returns-multiple-values-to-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Although this isn't related to your question, I would suggest that you don't use `type` as a keyword argument for your function as `type` is a built-in function in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You use the following code

```py
df[['c', 'd']] = df['a', 'b'].apply(calc, type='both', axis=1)
```

There are several issues:

1. To select multi columns, you need to use a list of column names, like `df[['a', 'b']]`.
2. [`pandas.DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) doesn't have `type` argument.
3. Since you use `axis=1`, `calc` should only take one argument which is the row of dataframe.

If you want to pass extra arguments to `calc`, you can do in two ways

1. Use `args` argument of `apply()`

```py
def calc(row, type):
    a = row['a']
    b = row['b']

    if type=='both':
        c = a+b
        d = a-b

    return c, d

df[['c', 'd']] = df[['a', 'b']].apply(calc, args=('both',), axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

2. You can use lambda funciton

```py
def calc(row, type):
    a = row['a']
    b = row['b']

    if type=='both':
        c = a+b
        d = a-b

    return c, d

df[['c', 'd']] = df[['a', 'b']].apply(lambda row: calc(row, 'both'), axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

At last, since `type` is a built-in function of Python. You'd better not use it as variable name.

A MRE

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})

def calc(row, type):
    a = row['a']
    b = row['b']

    if type=='both':
        c = a+b
        d = a-b

    return c, d

df[['c', 'd']] = df[['a', 'b']].apply(lambda row: calc(row, 'both'), axis=1, result_type='expand')

df[['e', 'f']] = df[['a', 'b']].apply(calc, args=('both',), axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

```
print(df)

   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  4  5 -3  5 -3
1  2  5  7 -3  7 -3
2  3  6  9 -3  9 -3
```

Comment: Tried both suggesstions: getting error case1 - TypeError calc() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis' case 2 - TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: @crybaby I added a MRE in my answer.